# How to calculate a dynamic average value between rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to calculate a dynamic average value between rows?

first 12 months status_flag is going to be `N` and from 13th month onward we need to take the average of sales for first 13 rows and compare it with min and max values and if it lies in between min and max then set the `status_flag` as `Y` else set it as `N`.

Same for 14th row take the average of first 14 rows and compare it with min and max... and so on.

How to do this?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I'm using Oracle, but this question is general. Not specific to Oracle. @jarlh

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing... Please try to rephrase it.

Comment: If you don't know whether or not you need to add a column to a table, worrying about code might be the least of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think the challenging part is to get the average sales. You can use the [Analytic Functions:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

```
select Storeid, Months, Min, Max, sales,
   avg(sales) over (order by Months RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as avg_sales
from your_table;
```

The rest should be easier. Note, `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is the default, so you can just skip it.

```
with a as 
   (select Storeid, Months, Min, Max, sales,
       avg(sales) over (order by Months) as avg_sales
    from your_table)
select  Storeid, Months, Min, Max, sales, avg_sales,
   case 
      when Months <= 12 then 'N'
   else
      case 
         when avg_sales between Min and Max then 'Y'
         else 'N'
      end 
   end as Status_flag
from a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update table t set status_flag =
   case when 
     (Select count(*)
      From table 
      where month <= t.Month) > 12
    and
     (select avg(sales)
      from table 
      where Month <= t.Month)
     Between Min and Max 
   then 'Y' else 'N' end
```